# CSS 3 Transitions - Flickering Content with Bootstrap 3.2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, transition

I am experiencing a strange flickering effect when attempting to use bootstrap 3.2 and css3 transitions to simulate a horizontal flipping effect.  The flipping happens but the content on the back side of the "Card" flickers rapidly during the transition.  I have included a JSFiddle of the problem.  This is happening in chrome.  In IE the back side of the card is not displayed at all after the transition.

I am using backface-visibility: hidden as seen in this code snippet

```
.flippable > figure {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w953nvpq/

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backface-visibility : hidden doesn't work because it needs transform-style: preserve-3d in the element itself, not in the parent

```
.flippable > figure {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

and now this is useless:

```
.flippable.flipped .front {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w953nvpq/1/)

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it had to be something simple!